# Selenium python to change the cookies of another site from one site

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-webdriver-python

I want to change a cookie outside the site I'm visiting with python selenium like this (this is my chrome tab not selenium browser)

[image: cookie]

The site I entered: https://2captcha.com/tr/demo/hcaptcha?difficulty=difficult
Cookie site I use from frame:
newassets.hcaptcha.com

At first I tried to do something like:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://newassets.hcaptcha.com')
cookie = {"name":"hc_accessibility","value":""}
driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.refresh()
time.sleep(2)
driver.get("https://2captcha.com/tr/demo/hcaptcha?difficulty=difficult")
time.sleep(2)
```

but when I entered the site, the hcaptcha_accecibilty cookies were not there  (this is my selenium browser tab)
[image: cookie2]